# Regex to delete all words containing numbers from a sentence

Tags: php, regex

I tried my best to remove all words in a sentence with numbers in them, but still unsuccessful! And I even tried the following regex:

```
$regex = '/(\\s+\\w{1,2}(?=\\W+))|(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\d+)/';
$x=preg_replace($regex,"",$x);
```

I'm trying to accomplish the following :

Original text with words containing numbers and any special character such as - and _:

```
This is S3F8G m7j34m h98H40D-3D39 90843-432423 LSDF3 4X4it very good 343c3.
```

Final text needs to be as follows:

```
This is very good.
```

Comment: What regex dialect is this? That is, what language are you using?

Comment: $regex = '/(\\s+\\w{1,2}(?=\\W+))|(\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\d+)/';

Comment: $x=preg_replace($regex,"",$x);

Comment: Just about all of these should be edited into the question (and PHP should be a tag). I did this for you.

Comment: Thanks Oded, will take care of this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wrote in Javascript:

```
var str = 'This is S3F8G m7j34m h98H40D-3D39 90843-432423 LSDF3 4X4it very good 343c3.';
var result = str.match(/(^[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+$|^[\D]+$)+/g).join('');
```

But you can try this in PHP:

```
<?
$str = 'This is S3F8G m7j34m h98H40D-3D39 90843-432423 LSDF3 4X4it very good 343c3.';;
preg_match_all("/(^[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+$|^[\D]+$)+/",$str,$result);
$result = implode('',$result[0]);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! That will be of great help too! But I'm in need of php based solution!

Comment: Well, I'm not very good with PHP, but I updated the answer with a code on it. Try and tell me if works

Comment: Yes, right Mark, I was about to post that :) Thanks, yes its working now! Thanks mate!

Comment: @Vishal and @Mark, this will not work with strings like `"valid consecutive words with single space between them"`.

Comment: Why not? I tried and worked perfectly... Did I miss something?

Comment: @Mark, I got a bit confused by this confusing expression, but here is a breaking example: http://jsfiddle.net/DVbav/ The last word is removed even tho it does not contain any numbers.

Comment: $str= 'This is very good - true';
    preg_match_all("/(^[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+$|^[\D]+$)+/",$str,$result);
    $result = implode('',$result[0]);
    echo $result;
@Mark, this is removing the trailing "- true" part!

Comment: In some cases its working correctly as in my first example, and in the second case, mine and yours, its truncating the last word.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$x="This is S3F8G m7j34m h98H40D-3D39 90843-432423 LSDF3 4X4it very good 343c3.";
$re="/ ?\b[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*\b/i";
print preg_replace($re, "", $x) . "\n";
```

returns:

```
This is very good.
```

One proviso: since this regex strips a leading space rather than a trailing one, if the FIRST word contains adigit, then the result will have a space prepended.  Thus:

```
<?php

$x="9abc foo bar.";
$re="/ ?\b[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*\b/i";
print preg_replace($re, "", $x) . "\n";
```

returns:

```
 foo bar
^
```

Comment: Thankx @ghoti!  Checking this too :)

Comment: Leading space problem could be avoided by an alteration matching the following space, like in my answer.

Comment: But that will degrade whitespace.  I guess we need to know if whitespace is important, or if a "word" for the OP's purposes is just the text, or is text+whitespace, or whitespace+text.

Comment: No it will not degrade anything, only upgrade. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

And here's a (hopefully) quirk free way ([ideone](http://ideone.com/iF7gS)):

```
$str = '-12x This is S3F8G m7j34m h98H40D-3D39 90843-432423 LSDF3 4X4it very good 343c3. foo bar';
echo preg_replace('/\s+[\w-]*\d[\w-]*|[\w-]*\d[\w-]*\s*/', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
This is very good. foo bar
```

Any special characters that you want to include as part of words you will need to add to the character classes.

Comment: This does not maintain whitespace.  Try it with a string of `"-12x This___is___S3F8G_good_343c3."`. (Underscores for spaces, since SO comments collapse whitespace.)

Comment: @ghoti, it does, eg: http://ideone.com/6H2Yc Each word is removed with one of the spaces around it. On which side the space is to be removed when there are two choices is not specified, so here it removes the space before it.