# replace words and strings pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

```
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24',
                                  'dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001',
                                  'mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok'], 
                          'IDs': ['A11','B22','C33'],
                          }) 

           Date                                 IDs
0   This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24      A11
1   dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001                 B22
2   mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok                  C33
```

I have the dataframe above. My goal is to replace all mixed word/number combo's WITHOUT hyphens `-` e.g. `1A1619I` or `BL171111` or `A13B` but NOT `1-22-2001` or `A-1-24` with the letter `M`. I have attempted to use the code below via [identify letter/number combinations using regex and storing in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650538/identify-letter-number-combinations-using-regex-and-storing-in-dictionary)

```
dataframe['MixedNum'] = dataframe['Date'].str.replace(r'(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(\S+\S+\S+)','M')
```

But I get this output

```
                          Date              IDs     MixedNum
0   This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24  A11     M M M M M M M
1   dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001             B22     M M M M 1-22-2001
2   mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok              C33     M M or M ok
```

when I would really want this output

```
                          Date              IDs     MixedNum
0   This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24  A11     This M person M the A-1-24 
1   dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001             B22     dont M but NOT 1-22-2001
2   mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok              C33     mix: M or M ok
```

I also tried the regex suggested here but it also didnt work for me
[Regex replace mixed number+strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453999/regex-replace-mixed-numberstrings)

Can anyone help me alter my regex?  `r'(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(\S+\S+\S+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
pat = r'(?<!\S)(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S)'
dataframe['MixedNum'] = dataframe['Date'].str.replace(pat, 'M')
```

Output:

```
>>> dataframe
                                     Date  IDs                    MixedNum
0  This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24  A11  This M person M the A-1-24
1             dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001  B22    dont M but NOT 1-22-2001
2              mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok  C33              mix: M or M ok
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string should immediately precede the current location
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])` - either

  - `[a-zA-Z]+\d` - 1+ letters and a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+[a-zA-Z]` - 1+ digits and a letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ digits or letters
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string should follow the current location immediately.